# ¿como exportar un proyecto .Net en visual estudio hacia otra solución?

Tags: .net

Tengo una solución en .NET con dos proyectos escritos en C#, en el primer proyecto tengo un programa en desarrollo, en el segundo proyecto tengo una clase con el método y los atributos perfectos para una conexión de consultas con MySQL, ¿De que manera puedo exportar este segundo proyecto a un tipo de archivo .dll o cualquiera que sea el formato adecuado para que posteriormente lo pueda integrar en otras soluciones futuras? y, ¿De qué manera se importaría a otra solución?, de manera que no tuviera que escribir nuevamente el código en mis futuras soluciones, únicamente importar este proyecto con la clase que necesito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click derecho sobre el proyecto y luego en compilar, luego de nuevo click derecho y abrir en el explorador, buscar la carpeta bin, debug, y ahi hay un .dll con el nombre de tu proyecto, si es que lo creaste como biblioteca de clases sino sera un .exe.

Comment: ¿De que manera importar entonces ese .dll a otra solución? y, ¿Como en el caso de que sea un .exe?